# Scalatra controller calling JSP page

Tags: jsp, scala, ssp

Is there any framework which users Scalatra as controller and use JSP pages for presentation. Iam trying to find one such framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play framework can be used with scala.

[Play Framework tutorial with Scala](http://codedefinition.com/blog/9-play-framework-tutorial-with-scala/)